# Uploading appx from electron builder to Windows Store giving Invalid package identity name ... (expected: XXXAppName)

Tags: windows-10-universal, electron-builder, appx

I'm trying to upload an appx file generated by electron builder to the windows store.

Unfortunately I'm now receiving the following error:
[image: windows app store error]

```
Invalid package identity name: Teselagen.OpenVectorEditor (expected: 56560Teselagen.OpenVectorEditor)

Invalid package family name: Teselagen.OpenVectorEditor_6fpmqnhnq2nc4 (expected: 56560Teselagen.OpenVectorEditor_6fpmqnhnq2nc4)
```

I'm not sure where those weird numbers are coming from or why that would be expected. Here's what my electron builder settings look like:

```
"build": {
    "appx": {
      "identityName": "Teselagen.OpenVectorEditor",
      "publisher": "CN=D373F92F-3481-433F-9DC5-0BE55DE5500D",
      "publisherDisplayName": "Teselagen",
      "applicationId": "OpenVectorEditor",
      "displayName": "OpenVectorEditor"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "appx"
    },
```

Does anyone know how to get around this or why those weird numbers would be expected. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

Ok.. after troubleshooting for quite a long time.. the following finally worked for me:

```
"build": {
    "appx": {
      "identityName": "56560Teselagen.OpenVectorEditor", //I changed this to include the identityName that was generated for me
      "publisher": "CN=D373F92F-3481-433F-9DC5-0BE55DE5500D",
      "publisherDisplayName": "Teselagen",
      "applicationId": "OpenVectorEditor", //need to include this otherwise it will default to the identityName which will break because applicationId isn't allowed to start with numbers
      "displayName": "OpenVectorEditor"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "appx"
    },
```

Originally I didn't realize that an identityName had been generated for me when I created a submission on the windows developer page. You can find your identityName here:

[image: windows page with identityName info]

Comment: This solved my issue, thanks!